# How to compile C file but limit the library usage?

Tags: c, unix, gcc, compilation

I'm working with a unix server.

I'm getting a c file as input from my client ,which i compile.

The c file should be very basic , and contain only functions from stdio , stdlib , math, string.

Is there any flag in GCC compiler that will not allow usage of any other library and will throw a compilation error in case other library is used?

If there is a solution not involving GCC it might be good too , but I don't want to inspect the file.

thanks.

Comment: Why not preprocess the file, rejecting any file with an include statement and then add in the four allowed includes. What you're doing sounds hideously insecure though.

Comment: @Dunes - I know thats insecure , thats why i want to limit the client to those libraries

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you want to verify that only certain header files are included by the preprocessor? `-MD` flag to gcc will give you dependent headers, you can verify that only allowed headers are there. Or do you want to verify that the compiled object only links with libc and libm? You can extract undefined symbols from the object file (`nm` or `objdump`, 'U' symbols) and verify they are all found in libc.so or libm.so or their static equivalents.

Comment: But you allow the inclusion of stdlib.h which has the system function in it. Using the system function and a little bit of creativity an attacker could run arbitrary code on your machine.

Comment: are your clients actually students submitting assignments?

Answer (score 6):

Limiting libraries (both header includes at compile time and library linkage at link time) is not going to stop untrusted code from directly calling dangerous (as in security-relevant) kernel syscalls. This could be done by the untrusted code e.g. by using inline assembly or shellcode/exploit techniques, for example by deliberately overwriting a return address on the stack to point to a string containing shellcode.

Having said that, you can use the `-nostdlib -nodefaultlibs` linker options to prevent linking to libraries. However, this will still only allow you to have either the whole of libc, or none of it. You cannot selectively link to only part of libc (say, have `printf()` but not `system()`).

Only allowing certain includes is not very effective either: code can just copy the declarations from the include files instead of including certain headers to get around a limitation to only allow specific `#include` statements. Example:

```
int system(const char *);
int main() {
    return system("uname -a");
}
```

If it has to be secure, you should probably look into sandboxing the code at runtime instead of trying to prevent insecure code from compiling.

Comment: If the goal is to sandbox compiled code, limiting libraries with `-nostdlib` or `-nodefaultlibs` doesn't help: a user can simply write inline assembly that performs a system call directly without using any standard library. Runtime sandboxing really is the only way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the option `-nodefaultlibs` or `-nostdlib` to gcc, along with options to include only the permitted libraries (like `-lm` for the math library). Check the [gcc manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) for more information on these options.

> **`-nodefaultlibs`**
>   Do not use the standard system libraries when linking.  Only the
>   libraries you specify will be passed to the linker.

Answer (score 1):

Just to illustrate how insecure you allowing the inclusion of stdlib.h is I'll write a small program that can run arbitrary code on your machine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("`which python` -c \"print 'hello word'\"");
    // instead of simply printing hello world i could open a socket back to the 
    // attacker's machine and start reading in abitrary code and executing it.
    return 0;
}
```